# Post to app page without logging in

Tags: wpf, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm currently working on a multi-user kiosk project in .NET/C#. The kiosk needs to post to its own Facebook page when users complete a specific action. We don't want users to log into their personal Facebook account on the kiosk.

I'm having a hard time figuring out if it's possible to have a Facebook app post directly to the associated app page without a user logging in. I've been looking into app access tokens, but it appears those tokens don't have enough privileges to post comments to a page.

I have created my Facebook app page and I was going to see if I could give my app permissions to post on that page, but it seems as though I can't actually add the app to the page until it has been approved by Facebook.

I'm really just trying to find out if what I'm trying to do is feasible and, if so, any direction anyone can point me in to figure this out would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this. Basically, in one way or another you are going to have to authenticate. You can store the access token and continue to use it, but you need to use OAuth to get an access token at some point.

It should be noted that this isn't anything to do with the Facebook C# SDK, but rather this is how Facebook's graph API works. You can read about Page auth here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-page/